# Powershell importing excel range to then export to SQL

Tags: excel, powershell

I am using the following powershell script to import a range in excel into powershell.

```
$rc1 = $ws.cells.find("German")

if ($rc1) 
    {
    $addr = $rc1.address(0, 0, 1, 0)
    do
        {
        $rc2 = $rc1.Offset(0,1)
        if ($rc2.Value2.Contains("Baseload")) 
        {
            $rc3 = $rc1.Offset(3, 0)
            $rangeStart = $rc3.Address(0,0,1,0)
            $rc4 = $rc1.offset(13,3)
            $rangeEnd = $rc4.Address(0,0,1,0)
            $fullRange = ($ws.Range($rangeStart, $rangeEnd)).value2
            $fullrange
        break}
        $rc1 = $ws.cells.findnext($rc1)
       # write-host $rc1.value2
       # write-host $rc2.value2
        } until ($addr -eq $rc1.address(0, 0, 1, 0))
    }
}
```

It looks for the string 'german' and then offsets one cell if it finds it and looks for the word 'baseload'  if it finds that it then gets the range of the data below it which is a known size.

The data appears in the following format (this is not all the data).

[image: Data from Excel]

After getting the data I want to save it into an sql table but as the powershell data is just a list I am not sure I am importing the data correctly from excel as it is not in a table format.  The excel range is 4 columns by 14 where as the data shown in powershell is a list.

Hope that makes sense.